# Get text of Annotations

Tags: java, gate

I am working on Information extraction in GATE embeded.I have tried the following code to get the text from the Annotations:

```
AnnotationSet annotationSet = doc.getAnnotations().get("Person");  
DocumentContent   personStr = annotationSet .getContent();
```

But the get.Content is unable to work in the annotation type.
So how can we get the text which is annotated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think that 
`gate.Utils.stringFor(doc, personAnnotation)`
is what you are looking for. Where `personAnnotation` is a single annotation from your `annotationSet`.

Answer (score 1):

@ashingel 's answer is correct, just adding code snippet, how to use it:

```
AnnotationSet annotationSet = doc.getAnnotations().get("Person");  
for (Annotation annotation : annotationSet) {
    String personStr = gate.Utils.stringFor(doc, annotation);
    System.out.println(personStr);
}
```